# Facebook OAuth requires two clicks for "Login with Facebook"?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm just getting started using Facebook's OAuth for my website... when "Login with Facebook" is clicked, the Facebook page comes up properly for login. However, when redirected back to my site, "Login with Facebook" is still there instead of "Logout". When "Login with Facebook" is clicked a second time, the page switches over properly (without redirecting them to facebook a second time). Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: What happens when you refresh your page when arriving back to your site? Are you retrieving / assigning the token before you do your check if user is logged in?

Comment: are you using any of the FB js functions or just php? you may need to set the return url to a page which redirects back to the original page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out. It wasn't a problem with my code. I had to go into my setting on the facebook app settings and set the following (I'm working from localhost).

```
Site URL: http://localhost.local/
Site Domain: localhost.local
```

Comment: Facebook shouldn't even allow you to authenticate without errors unless the registered appid is same domain as the return url.